# Simple Haskell program not behaving correct

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and trying to write simple program to find maximal element and it's index from intput. I receive values to compare one by one. Maximal element I'm holding in **maxi** variable, it's index - in **maxIdx**. Here's my program:

```
loop = do
    let maxi = 0
    let maxIdx = 0
    let idx = 0
    let idxN = 0
    replicateM 5 $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let element = read input_line :: Int

        if maxi < element
        then do 
            let maxi = element
            let maxIdx = idx
            hPutStrLn stderr "INNER CHECK"
        else
            hPutStrLn stderr "OUTER CHECK"

        let idx = idxN + 1
        let idxN = idx

        print maxIdx

    loop
```

Even though I know elements coming are starting from bigger to smaller (5, 4, 3, 2, 1) program enters INNER CHECK all the time (it should happen only for the first element!) and **maxIdx** is always 0.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try printing out `maxi` on each iteration; that should give you a hint. Besides, I don't think you're using Haskell the best way.

Comment: How can I pring int value in **hPutStrLn stderr ...**? Yes, I know I'm not usuing it the best way, I'm just trying it :).

Comment: The point is, those aren't "variables" in that they don't _vary._ Those are values, and the scope is limited to the `do` operator you're currently in.

Comment: How can I do it then?

Comment: You should pick up a book like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) and learn how to write programs functionally. If you're coming from an imperative language, you may have picked up the (bad) habit of relying on the mutability of the references and the data structures in your program. When you write in Haskell, you just have to kick this bad habit; you have to start thinking in ways that respect the immutability of the things you name. I came to Haskell from Java/Scala, and let me tell you, thinking functionally takes some time (but it's worth it). LYAH will get you started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anyway, let's have fun.

```
loop = do
    let maxi = 0
    let maxIdx = 0
    let idx = 0
    let idxN = 0
    replicateM 5 $ do
        input_line <- getLine
        let element = read input_line :: Int

        if maxi < element
        then do 
            let maxi = element
            let maxIdx = idx
            hPutStrLn stderr "INNER CHECK"
        else
            hPutStrLn stderr "OUTER CHECK"

        let idx = idxN + 1
        let idxN = idx

        print maxIdx

    loop
```

is not a particularly Haskelly code (and as you know is not particularly correct).

Let's make if Haskellier.

What do we do here? We've an infinite loop, which is reading a line 5 times, does something to it, and then calls itself again for no particular reason.

Let's split it:

```
import Control.Monad

readFiveLines :: IO [Int]
readFiveLines = replicateM 5 readLn

addIndex :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
addIndex xs = zip xs [0..]

findMaxIndex :: [Int] -> Int
findMaxIndex xs = snd (maximum (addIndex xs))

loop :: ()
loop = loop

main :: IO ()
main = do xs <- readFiveLines
          putStrLn (show (findMaxIndex xs))
```

`snd` returns the second element from a tuple; `readLn` is essentially `read . getLine`; `zip` takes two lists and returns a list of pairs; `maximum` finds a maximum value.

I left `loop` intact in its original beauty.

You can be even Haskellier if you remember that `something (huge expression)` can be replaced with `something $ huge expression` (`$` simply applies its left operand to its right operand), and the functions can be combined with `.`: `f (g x)` is the same as `(f . g) x`, or `f . g $ x` (see? it's working for the left side as well!). Additionally, `zip x y` can be rewritten as `` x `zip` y ``

```
import Control.Monad

readFiveLines :: IO [Int]
readFiveLines = replicateM 5 readLn

addIndex :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
addIndex = (`zip` [0..])

findMaxIndex :: [Int] -> Int
findMaxIndex = snd . maximum . addIndex

main :: IO ()
main = do xs <- readFiveLines
          putStrLn . show . findMaxIndex $ xs
```

As for debug print, there's a package called `Debug.Trace` and a function `traceShow` which prints its first argument (formatted with `show`, hence the name) to `stderr`, and returns its second argument:

```
findMaxIndex :: [Int] -> Int
findMaxIndex = snd . (\xs -> traceShow xs (maximum xs)) . addIndex
```

That allows you to tap onto any expression and see what's coming in (and what are the values around — you can `show` tuples, lists, etc.)

Comment: How can I create an empty list?

Comment: I would really suggest you to refer to [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), namely the [chapter on lists](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists)—it is not exactly a question you ask on Stack Overflow. But while we're on it, try `[]`

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and it works as it should ^^. I had bad times trying to make it work, without knowing all that `snd`, `zip` and `maximum`, and also thinking NOT in a functional way :).

Answer (score 0):

I think alf's answer is very good, but for what it's worth, here's how I would interpret your intention.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import System.IO
import Control.Monad.State

data S = S { maximum :: Int
           , maximumIndex :: Int
           , currentIndex :: Int }

update :: Int -> Int -> S -> S
update m mi (S _ _ ci) = S m mi ci

increment :: S -> S
increment (S m mi ci) = S m mi (ci+1)

next :: (MonadIO m, MonadState S m) => m ()
next =  do
  S maxi maxIdx currIdx <- get

  input <- liftIO $ getLine
  let element = read input :: Int

  if maxi < element
  then do
    modify (update element currIdx)
    liftIO $ hPutStrLn stderr "INNER CHECK"
  else
    liftIO $ hPutStrLn stderr "OUTER CHECK"

  modify increment

run :: Int -> IO S
run n = execStateT (replicateM_ n next) (S 0 0 0)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  S maxi maxIdx _ <- run 5    
  putStrLn $ "maxi: " ++ (show maxi) ++ " | maxIdx: " ++ (show maxIdx)
```

This uses a monad transformer to combine a stateful computation with IO. The `get` function retrieves the current state, and the `modify` function lets you change the state.

Comment: No offense, but this answer isn't particularly helpful for a beginner who doesn't understand how Haskell works yet.

Comment: No offense taken.  If might help someone someday.

Comment: Not a particularly helpful answer, I think. In there you get Monads, lifts and the state monad. Not too over the top, I admit, but inappropriate for the beginner, before having read his first book.

Comment: @FredrikKarlsson Thanks for the feedback. As I stated, I think alf's answer is very good. However, I don't think it does what the poster's original program intended without the use of `traceShow` which should only be used for debugging. These questions and answers are available to the entire internet, so I think it's fair to add a version with 'proper' IO lest someone stumble across this questions and think `traceShow` is an appropriate solution. Also, I think its insulting to assume that just because someone is a beginner, they don't have the capacity to appreciate an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was helpful for me: I would _love_ to be able to write this version as well, but had neither working knowledge of monad transformers nor the dedication to learn that for a toy problem. It is true indeed that most probably it's out of the OP's depth (it's certainly borderline out of mine), but saying that the answer is "bad" because it's hard is completely missing the point, see https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy for example (I agree it's not only hard but also complex, but comparing two solutions is extremely valuable, don't you think?).